# Basis of the polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I show that the polynomials: $(1, 1+x, x+x^2)$ are the basis of $P_2$, the vector-space of polynomials of degree $2$?

I tried to show that they are linear dependent thus, $$a + b(1+x) + c(x+x^2) = 0$$ However, I fail to continue.

Comment: Your approach is good. Why did you stop?

Comment: Since this is tagged with "linear algebra": When talking about polynomials it is always good to specify the field/ring you are considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a + b(1+x) + c(x+x^2) = 0$$ must hold for all $x$.

For $x=-1,0,1$, this reduces to $$\begin{cases}a=0,\\a+b=0,\\a+2b+2c=0.\end{cases}$$

The conclusion is clear.

Comment: Thank you, this made it clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

For another approach,  write
$$
\pmatrix{ 1 \\ 1+x \\ x+x^2}
=
\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1}
\pmatrix{ 1 \\ x \\ x^2}
$$
and note that the matrix is invertible.

More generally, this argument proves that a set containing exactly one polynomial of each degree is a basis for the space of polynomials up to a certain degree. The corresponding matrix will be lower triangular with no zero diagonal entries.